# Tablix inside Rectangle inside Textbox not visible when report renders

Tags: textbox, ssrs-2008-r2, rectangles, ssrs-tablix

I have built a report with a list of caveats at the end within a text box.  Inside this list I need to display a table of static text.  The only way I have found to show the table is to put a rectangle inside the text box and place the table inside the rectangle.  However when I preview the report the table does not show.  Also when in design mode if I click outside of the rectangle into the text box both the rectangle and table disappear and only reappear when I use the scroll bar.  I have checked that both the rectangle and table are visible and have tried moving to front and moving back but it does not change.  Can anyone point me in the right direction please.
To help with explanation I have added screenshots:
Image 1 - showing table in rectangle in text box in design view
[image]
Table 2 - showing result of preview where table should show
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I had been thinking straight and built this from scratch I would never have tried to do it the way I did.  I suddenly realised that the answer was simple.  Put a rectangle first then populate it with 2 textboxes and put the static text table between the 2 textboxes.  The rectangle holds it all together and can have a border if required.